# Karate: How to run scenario multiple times sending a List of strings

Tags: karate

So basically I have a scenario where the "Get list of available endpoints" and "Test endpoints" have the same payload

```
{
  "endpoint": "#(endpoint)",
  "propertyId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
  "payload_prospect": {
    "FirstName" :"Mike",
    "SpectrumPersonID" : "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "Phone1" :"555-555-5555"
  }
}
```

When I send the first request (Get list of available endpoints), i send the {"endpoint" : "list"}

```
{
  "endpoint": "List",
  "propertyId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
  "payload_prospect": {
    "FirstName" :"Mike",
    "SpectrumPersonID" : "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "Phone1" :"555-555-5555"
  }
}
```

As response, i get a list of available endpoints to test. This list depends on the dev team, sometimes i can get 3 values and some others 10.

```
{
    "value 1": {
        "foo1": "aaa",
        "foo2": "bbb",
        "foo3": "ccc"
    },
    "value 2": {
        "foo1": "aaa",
        "foo2": "bbb",
        "foo3": "ccc"
    },
    "value 3": {
        "foo1": "aaa",
        "foo2": "bbb",
        "foo3": "ccc"
    }
}
```

i want to take those values (value 1, value 2, value 3) and iterate them in a scenario.

```
Feature: Endpoints

Background:
    # Get token
    Given def appToken= callonce read('classpath:utils/features/auth/appToken.feature')
    And def token = appToken.authToken
    # Get list of available endpoints
    Given url baseUrl
    And path 'externalResourceClient'
    And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
    And def endpoint = 'list'
    And def requestBody = read('classpath:jsonfiles/requests/curlcalls/apigee/apigeeRequest.json')
    And request requestBody
    And retry until responseStatus == 200
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    And def endpoints = jsonOperations.getJsonKeys(response)


Scenario Outline: Test endpints
    Given url baseUrl
    And path 'externalResourceClient'
    And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
    # And def endpoint = <endpoint>
    And def requestBody = read('classpath:jsonfiles/requests/curlcalls/apigee/apigeeRequest.json')
    And request requestBody
    And retry until responseStatus == 200
    When method GET
    Then status 200

Examples:
| endpoint |
| endpoints |
```

Unfortunatelly, this implementation sends all the endpoints as request

```
{
  "endpoint": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"],
  "propertyId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
  "payload_prospect": {
    "FirstName" :"Mike",
    "SpectrumPersonID" : "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "Phone1" :"555-555-5555"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using Karate 1.3.1 and shows how you can loop over an HTTP end-point. Here are the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup

```
Feature:

@setup
Scenario:
* def data = [ { myNum: 1 }, { myNum: 2 }, { myNum: 3 } ]

Scenario Outline:
* url `https://httpbin.org/anything/${myNum}`
* method get

Examples:
| karate.setup().data |
```

There are many other ways to "loop". Note that massaging the JSON you have into a "loopable" data-source is simple, for example:

```
* def list = 
"""
{
  'value 1': {
    foo1: 'aaa',
    foo2: 'bbb',
    foo3: 'ccc'
  },
  'value 2': {
    foo1: 'aaa',
    foo2: 'bbb',
    foo3: 'ccc'
  },
  'value 3': {
    foo1: 'aaa',
    foo2: 'bbb',
    foo3: 'ccc'
  }
}
"""
* def result = []
* karate.forEach(list, (k, v)=> result.push(v))
* print result
```

For more tips search the docs for "JSON transforms".