# Capture an ids from API-1 and pass it into another API-2 path and execute dynamically

Tags: api, automation, karate, web-api-testing

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "location": "usa"
    },
    {
        "id": 2322,
        "location": "japan"
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "location": "uk"
    }
]
```

I have captured the all `locationId`s into a variable called `locationId`. But, I need to iterate the list of `locationId` dynamically for another API path.

`GETGET https://example.com/location/<idNo>`

Eg:

- `iteration1: https://example.com/location/1`
- `iteration2: https://example.com/location/2322`
- `iteration3: https://example.com/location/33`

Is this possible?

What is the right approact to implement the above example by using Karate Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75027059/143475

```
Feature:

  @setup
  Scenario:
    * def data = [ { id: 1, location: 'usa' }, { id: 2322, location: 'japan' }, { id: 33, location: 'uk' } ]

  Scenario Outline:
    * url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
    * path id
    * method get

    Examples:
      | karate.setup().data |
```

Comment: Awesome,
It is working as expected when the data is hardcoded in the feature file.

Suppose, if we are calling test data management api which already displays the list of Ids. On the fly, can I pass the list of Ids to another API Path? It means, we hitting an API and capture all Ids as an array and pass them to another API request Path(Dynamically)

Comment: @PSP yes. you can put any logic in the `@setup`, even API calls and pre-process a JSON array (of objects) which can be used to loop

Comment: Thanks @Peterthomas let me try will come back if I have any question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, if we are calling test data management api which already displays the list of Ids. On the fly, can I pass the list of Ids to another API Path? It means, we hitting an API and capture all Ids as an array and pass them to another API request Path(Dynamically)

```
Feature:

  @setup
  Scenario: Test data for get the list of Id
    Given url 'https://httpbin.org/anything1'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    And print response
    *  def data = $[*].Id
   

  Scenario Outline:
    * url 'https://httpbin.org/anything2'
    * path id
    * method get

    Examples:
      | karate.setup().data |
```

Comment: yes you are on the right track